# Runtime directory of Python

Tags: python, working-directory

How do I find out the current runtime directory from within a Python script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`os.getcwd`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.getcwd). This will tell you the *current working directory*. If you create a new file with

```
fp = open('a.txt', 'w')
```

then `a.txt` will be created in the current working directory. Use [`os.chdir`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chdir) to change the working directory, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.

```
os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.getcwd()` will change when u use `os.chdir`

If you need a fixed path to your python file, use:

```
module_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```